# How can I use "sudo mount -o loop factoryfs.ext4 factoryfs" in Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, sudo

Does Cygwin have a command equivalent to `sudo mount -o loop factoryfs.ext4 factoryfs`? If so, what is it?

Comment: I think you're missing a "mount" in there somewhere...

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't mount filesystem images using Cygwin. Cygwin mount supports only mounting Windows directories/disks to directories inside Cygwin. See for example http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#mount-table

Workaround for some filesystems is to mount disk as normal Windows disk and then mount that to Cygwin. For example [ext2](http://www.fs-driver.org/) is supported in Windows with additional drivers.